# Determining variable rank with unknown shape in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When creating a variable in tensorflow with `validate_shape=False`, it also ignores the variable rank:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
v = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(x), trainable=False, validate_shape=False)
tf.layers.dense(v, 10)

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_5 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

In this case, while the exact variable shape must be dynamic, I know what its rank is going to be. Is there some way to inform it to tensorflow, so I can use operations that need to know the input rank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with `tf.reshape()`:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
v = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(x), trainable=False, validate_shape=False)
#tf.layers.dense(v, 10)
tf.layers.dense(tf.reshape(v,[-1,10]),10)
```

where the `-1` allows the return tensor to have shape `(?,10)`; namely the output of the above is:

```
<tf.Tensor 'dense_10/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
```

which is what you want.  You can verify correct behavior by using a known shape and toggling `validate_shape`, as in:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5, 10])
v = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(x), trainable=False, validate_shape=True)
tf.layers.dense(v, 10)
```

...returns the same as:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5, 10])
v = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(x), trainable=False, validate_shape=False)
tf.layers.dense(tf.reshape(v,[5,10]),10)

# returns <tf.Tensor 'dense_8/BiasAdd:0' shape=(5, 10) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me out fix a similar issue here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442263/converting-a-numpy-function-into-tensor-flow