# How to get a placeholder from a list of placeholders using a placeholder in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a list of placeholders as follows:

```
input_vars = []
input_vars.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 5], dtype=tf.float32, name="place0"))
input_vars.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 5], dtype=tf.float32, name="place1"))
input_vars.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 5], dtype=tf.float32, name="place2"))
```

I want to access different placeholders based on a int placeholder as follows:

```
which_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
```

When calling the following in session:

```
input_vars[which_input]
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tensor

I tried using tf.gather which worked, however when I want to feed the selected placeholder in the dense layer as follows:

```
helpme = tf.gather(input_vars, which_input)
l_in = tf.layers.dense(inputs=helpme, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu, trainable=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_4 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.

Here is the session running info:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5]]
x.append([6,7,8,9,10])

y = [[5,4,3,2,1]]
y.append([5,3,2,1,1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    dictd = dict()
    dictd[input_vars[0]] = x
    dictd[input_vars[1]] = y
    dictd[input_vars[2]] = x
    dictd[which_input] = 2

    print sess.run(l_in, feed_dict=dictd)
```

Am I missing something? How can this be done?

Comment: What is the actual underlying task that you are trying to solve? Maybe there is a workaround that does not require a "placeholder of placeholders".

Comment: @mikkola I have a computation graph which requires to feed the same neural network different kind of inputs (input_vars) to compute the loss function. Hence the need.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. You don't need to feed them all concurrently, just one at a time? What kind of a signature does the loss function have, then?

Comment: @mikkola : There are multiple parts of the loss function. Each part requires the same neural network to evaluate a **different** input and produce an output. This produced output is then used to compute the loss function. For example,

`loss = loss_1 + loss_2;`

`loss_1` requires me to feed `input_var[0]` to NN, get its output, convert to scalar and add to loss function. Similarly, `loss_2` requires me to feed `input_var[1]` to NN, get its output, convert to scalar and add to loss function.

So overall, I should be able to choose which input to give to NN in the same computational graph.

Comment: Perhaps you could feed both `input_vars` in separate placeholders at the same time, and set up your computational graph to process both using the same network? You should be able to do this if you set up the network to have two identical branches that [share the variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables), such as weights and biases.

Comment: @mikkola: Thanks. This may work. Actually all I need is to evaluate the same NN with different inputs in the same computational graph. If input is a single placeholder, I can't pass different values to it in sess.run() to compute my loss. Anyways, I was hoping to find some tricky way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reshape your output from tf.gather as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272017/determining-variable-rank-with-unknown-shape-in-tensorflow) answer:

```
l_in = tf.layers.dense(inputs=tf.reshape(helpme, shape=[-1,5]), units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu, trainable=True)
```